# Convert base64 string to image in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

### **Problem**

I created a social media app with expo's react native, and wanted to add the ability to upload images. Since expo won't let you convert a file to a blob to upload, I just uploaded the base64 image data as a string to the server database. How can I convert this data into the viewable image again after I download the data from off of the server?

Comment: Instead of trying to upload the image as a blob, create a form and attach the image as a file. You shouldn't store images in a database, you should store them as files that are referenced from the database. See this for an example: https://github.com/g6ling/React-Native-Tips/tree/master/How_to_upload_photo%2Cfile_in%20react-native

Comment: you can use [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) to convert image to base64 and then again back to image from base64.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var base64Icon = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...';
<Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}} source={{uri: base64Icon}}/>
```

In the `base64Icon` variable you need to put your base64 data after `data:image/png;base64,`. Like this:

```
var base64Icon = 'data:image/png;base64,{PLACE_YOUR_BASE64_DATA_HERE}';
```

Comment: <Image source={{ uri: `data:image/png;base64,${item.appIcon}`}}   am getting base64 icon from api but in react native web not showing the app icon

Comment: What to do if we want to download it ?