# How to create directory or files on the internal storage of android device in react native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

How can I create a directory on the internal storage of an android device, using react-native? I do not want to use any library like ReactNativeFS, etc.

The possible solution, you might suggest is to write your own module. But I am not good at Java or Kotlin. And if I knew Kotlin or Java then I would not have used the framework React Native.

Earlier, I faced problems storing data in SQLite, and I found no way to do it inside react native. The only way to do it is to depend on some external libraries. The framework itself cannot do anything. It seems to be just branding for Facebook, since everything in this framework requires a dependency.

Is there any way to do this without any external dependencies/modules?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763209/how-do-i-save-a-picture-from-expo-image-picker-to-expo-file-system-and-then-rend

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I got my answer. It is just switch from React Native to Android Studio with Kotlin as a tool.

Comment: Why don't you like to use a dependency like react native FS.. isn't it safe????

Comment: Dependencies create security vulnerabilities in your application, the more you have more vulnerable your application becomes, so we try to minimize dependencies and afterall a framework doesn't ask you to install dependency for such stuff, if it does then it's not a good framework.

Comment: I agree but react itself, is famous for libraries.. or else you can (or one with needed requirements) should create there own library (packages) ..... I think big companies create their own npm packages .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question in mind like you, But I later discover a fix.

Please follow these steps:

1. Install rn-fetch-blob package, [here is the doc](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob)
2. Go to your AndriodManifest.xml add  =>   `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` inside your application tag, like this `<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"  ... />`
3. At your root android/build.gradle change this:

   ```
    buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    targetSdkVersion = 29
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but it's adds just another dependency, I just wanted to answer my own question? What exactly is framework? I want you too to ask the same question from yourself. You will see that: A framework is not something that depends on other dependencies for every small bit of functionality. E.g of framework You want navigation, just use this function, A framework doesn't say you to install another dependency or package, because frameworks are not meant to be like that. It is the proper definition of a framework. The point that needs to be clear is : What is a framework? good luck everyone.